# How to group nearest blobs using EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, imaging

I have many b/w images with black little objects.
I use FindContour using c# with EmguCV V2.4.10 to detect each blob, so far so good, but how can i group blobs of nearest distance to each other.

I heard about Watershed segmentation but i don't know how to accomplish this task.
I would appreciate any solution approaches...

Result Sample of grouped Blobs:

```
|* * *    |          |   ** **** ** |
| *  *  * |          |****          |
| *     * |          |*   *** ***   |
| *  *  * |          |****        **|



      |*** ** *|
      |** *** *|
      |** ** **|
```

Comment: maybe you wanna take a look here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842940/clustering-image-segments-in-opencv/23997322#23997322

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it by yourself use Find-Union or DFS algorithm.
In Find-Union first all 'stars' are in separated boxes and then connect neighbours. (using appropiate connectivity algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity - probably 8 connectivity will give you best results. )